# Loss function for Generative AI

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network

How do we keep implementing negative loss functions so conveniently in generative models and use Adam and other such optimisers on them. These optimisers are meant to work with non-negative loss values right and their target is to minimise loss function how would they behave if we give them a negative loss function? And how does this seem to work for a generative model shouldn't the behaviour become unexpected and give rise to divergence issues?

I tried searching for answers online but was unable to find any good reasoning on how this works.

Comment: In gradient descent-based optimization algorithms like Adam, the direction of the gradient guides the parameter updates. As long as the gradients of the negative loss function are well-defined and continuous, the optimizer can effectively navigate the parameter space towards minimizing the negative loss.

Comment: In generative models, the loss function most of the times represents a measure of dissimilarity between the generated samples and the target samples. Using negative loss function, you allow the generator to produce samples that are more similar to the target samples.